# Return count 1,2,3,4.... for duplicates in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column with duplicate account #, and the number of repeats is different for each account.

I'm hoping to formulate a column that returns 1 for the first instance, 2 for the second instance, 3 for the third, and so on.  Ideal result looks like this:

ideal outcome

[image]

Comment: Look into COUNTIF

Comment: ^^^ ie: `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)` pay special attention to what is and what is not absolute.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! @ScottCraner

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N($A$1:A1=A1))
```

[image]